# Javascript .replace new line within search string (not targeting?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written this quick but of code:

```
var navTitle = $('#nav ul').html();
    var replacer = navTitle.replace('<li class="page_item page-item-73">
    <a href="xxx/">x training programme</a><ul class=\'children\'>', 
    '<li class="page_item page-item-73"><a href="xxx/">x training programme</a
    <ul id="longDropdown" class=\'children\'>');
    console.log(replacer);
    //$('#nav ul').html(replacer);
```

In the HTML it appears like this:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-73"><a href="xxx/">x training programme</a>
<ul class='children'>
```

I tried putting a \n after the  in the search string however the string is not changing, I think it cannot find the src string.

Is the issue here the new line? I believe so however cannot target it.

Comment: why not just adding an attr id to the ul ?? look at the html as dom not as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery offers the `.replaceWith()` and `.replaceAll` methods.

```
$('#nav ul .page_item.page-item-73 a').replaceWith('<a href="xxx/"x training programme</a>');
```

Maybe even changing the text content or inner HTML will do for you

```
$('#nav ul .page_item.page-item-73 a').text('x training programme');
```

respectively

```
$('#nav ul .page_item.page-item-73 a').html('x training programme');
```

Comment: he's not replacing x training program he's adding an id to the ul

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just select the ul and then use .attr to add the ID?

```
var navTitle = $('#nav ul ul.children').attr('id', 'longdropdown');
```

Manipulating the DOM tends to be a lot tidier and safer than doing string replaces.

Comment: prop change javscript object property, attr is to be used to modify the html